# Java: Simple Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I'm making this array where the first number in the array should be 15 and the third as well. Then I need to print the array on the screen but I get an error when I do this, I've read that I got to write a loop when printing an array. How's that possible?

This is my current code.

```
    int[] i = {15,0,15,0,0};
    System.out.println(i);
```

And what's the difference in using this method or using

```
int [] i = new int [5];
```

Thanks in advance,

Michael.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a loop like this:

```
for(int j=0; j < i.length; j++) {
  System.out.println("Value at index " + j + ": " + i[j]");
}
```

Answer (score 5):

To print an array use `Arrays.toString()`;

```
import java.util.Arrays;

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(i));


// or print it in the loop
for(int e : i) {
   System.out.print(e);
}
```

About differences between two methods:

```
int [] i = new int [5]; // five evements are allocated

// the number of elements are determined by the initialization block
int[] i = {15,0,15,0,0};
```

Comment: Like this?

int[] i = {12,0,12,0,0};
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(i));

That doesn't work. Do I need to import something to be able to use it? And isn't it better with a loop? That's just what I've heard so I'm wondering how to print it as a loop. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[That code executes just fine](http://ideone.com/BVVRo), although it's probably not the string you expect as the default value for [`toString()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) (which is what gets executed) is defined as:

```
getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
```

To print the actual contents of the string you should employ the method suggested by e.g., @Oleg.

The statement `int[] i = {15,0,15,0,0};` is just shorthand for the more verbose

```
 int [] i = new int [5];
 i[0] = 15;
 i[1] = 0;
 i[2] = 15;
 i[3] = 0;
 i[4] = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's considered a "mistake" in java that there's no implementation for toString() - you get java.lang.Object implementation.

Instead, you must use the static method [Arrays.toString(array)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29).

Writing this `int [] i = new int [5];` *allocates* memory for 5 elements, but they are all intitialized to zero (`0`). You would have to write more code to assign values to the elements.

Answer (score 0):

Either you could print like this:

```
for (int index=0; index<i.length; index++)
System.out.println("Array's value at index " + index  + "is: " + i[index] );
```

Or you can use toString() function.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the two is that

```
int[] i = {15,0,15,0,0};
System.out.println(i);
```

the elements are determined by a initialization block , while

```
int [] i = new int [5];
```

five elements are allocated in the `int i`.